# How can I load an HTML stored in my assets folder "in the project solution" in a WPF, and be compiled too?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, assets

How can I load an HTML stored in my assets folder "in the project solution" in a WPF, and be compiled too
I need to have the executable application to work from any other computer with the same HTML, referencing to the assets folder ..
so simply..
here'e a screen shoot of my solution
what shall i type in my web browser's URL?

[image: Solution explorer]